# How to get the size of a table in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I want to khnow what is the size of a table in Cassandra.

Is there a query in cqlsh similar to `show dbs` in mongodb?

If not is there another way to get the size of tables?

Comment: what do you mean by size? list of tables or size of tables?

Comment: size of tables in MBs

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
nodetool cfstats -- <keyspace>.<table>
```

will give you the 'Space used' by a table.

Comment: But is this not the stats per node? Any way to get the info of the entire cluster?

Comment: Is there a way (outside of nodetool) to get access to this information?  via CQL or any API (OpsCenter?)

Comment: @shivsky nodetool uses JMX to get it's stats anyway so you can use JMX to do the same thing.

Comment: and just in case someone was wondering, the units are bytes (https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsCFstats.html)

Comment: This is incomplete, at best. tablestats/cfstats gives the size used by the SSTables on the disk, and on a per-node basis. The op was asking the size of the table. Even if you sum up all the "Space used" from all nodes, it's still not certain that it represents the table size. You might have superseded data taking up space.
Unfortunately, I don't think you can never get a proper size metric unless you compact everything and divide that for the RF.

Comment: That is partly why I emphasized the "Space used". The op was asking for the size of table in MBs which means (to me) the amount of space used on disk. Whether that is a misinterpretation or not, it is the closest you are going to get to it. I completely agree with you though that the actual size of active data in a table is extremely difficult to calculate at a point in time.